# Exception no longer being caught

Tags: exception

The following code was working fine. I then transported the files to another location (another instance of VS2019 Community). Now, the exception doesn't get caught any more and the code breaks during debug. How can this be explained? Thanks

```
 private List<string> getMembers(string objectName)
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        List<string> listMembers = new List<string>();

        try
        {                
            PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain);
            UserPrincipal up = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, IdentityType.SamAccountName, objectName);
            string groupList = "";
            foreach (var group in up.GetGroups())
            {
                groupList += group.SamAccountName + "|";                    
            }
            result.Add(objectName + tab + groupList);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result.Add(objectName + tab + "Error: " + ex.Message);
        }

        return result;

    }
```

Comment: How is the code breaking? And what exception are you expecting to be caught?

Comment: For example if the userPrincipal up returns an invalid result (the group object does not exist), on my first machine that is caught as a System.NullReferenceException: 'Ibject reference not set to an instance of an object'.

Comment: ...However, after I moved this code to another machine, although the exception is still thrown, it's no longer trapped by the Catch statement.

Comment: ..App runs just fine and exception is caught as desired outside of VS.

Comment: What do you mean, it runs fine and the exception is caught outside of VS? How do you know the exception is thrown? There's really not enough detail here to answer your question, I'm afraid...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case of corrupted/missing pdb files. Nothing wrong with code.